# Clean way to have a function accept u16 and usize, including unconstrained small positive integer literals

Tags: generics, rust, type-conversion

I'd like to have a function accept both `u16` and `usize`, and be able to call it those ways:

```rust
usu(1 as usize);           // 1
usu([1,2].len());          // 2
usu(3u16);                 // 3
let u16 = 4u16; usu(u16);  // 4
usu(5);                    // 5
```

Defining the `usu` function as `fn usu<U: Into<usize>>(u: U) {` doesn't work for test case 5 because `5`, being an unconstrained literal, is interpreted as `i32` by the compiler.

I don't want to use `unsafe` or have an added runtime cost, nor do I want users of my crate to use macros, import traits, or constrain their literals, just to use the `usu` function.

Is there a reasonable way to make `usu` accept both `u16` and `usize` (Rust edition 2021) ?

[test playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=064081f0de25bc88ea9c26953fc96208)

Comment: You can try [`num::Integer`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/trait.Integer.html), although this will accept more than just `u16` and `usize`

Comment: @BallpointBen Can you clarify (with a playground, perhaps) how that would make my API accept both types without making users import traits ? The goal is to have an easier to use API.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, uhm, maybe it do not fit to your requirements exaclty, but for fun would this help in any way? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=879d0d6ab2c7140cf936bcdb6c8b0215

Comment: I think it's not possible, you either need to give up u16 or integer https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=25fafb69fb709866a568d0dfcea77907

Comment: @Stargateur You're probably right. I asked just in case somebody had a solution. It looks wrong that we can't do something looking so simple.

Comment: This question may have to wait for generics `where` clauses supporting the `OR` to get an answer.

Comment: [This code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7cab4cbb4ae76a5a0281c393d53c190) passes your tests, but has the downside of failing at runtime when you call it with a value that is negative or larger than `usize::MAX`.